# Get string resources in viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, viewmodel

I need to show value in percent in TextView like "15 %"
I do it in viewModel by this way and it works:

```
                    perfusionIndexValue.postValue(
                        list.lastOrNull()?.perfusionIndex?.takeIf {
                            it != PerfusionIndex.NO_DATA
                        }?.value?.toString().orEmpty() + " %"
                    )
```

but if i do it with resources:

```
                    perfusionIndexValue.postValue(
                        list.lastOrNull()?.perfusionIndex?.takeIf {
                            it != PerfusionIndex.NO_DATA
                        }?.value?.toString().orEmpty() + Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.pi_percent)
                    )
```

I get

```
io.reactivex.rxjava3.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0e0081
```

How i can set text like "15 %"

Comment: why aren't you just passing in context to get your string ?

Comment: what do you mean? I'm just a junior developer and just learning

Comment: take context as a parameter for whatever this method is, then use context.getString(R.string.pi_percent)

Comment: i can't send context as parameter when i call this method

Comment: why ? how do you expect to get resources without some sort of reference to context ?

Comment: okey. What i can send as context in my Fragment, where a call this metod?

Comment: use getApplication() as context if context is not available.

Comment: the same: `lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference`. With ctrl+this string i I see that this string exists

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case I see you need here Context.

However, the Context of the Fragment or the Activity should not be passed into the ViewModel. Only use Application Context to get resources, ... or something related to Application in ViewModel.

Here, if you are not using Hilt (or Dagger) then you should replace `ViewModel()` to `AndroidViewModel(application)` as below:

```
class MyViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    ...
}
```

If using Hilt, you can inject the Application Context via the `@ApplicationContext` annotation like below without having to extend `AndroidViewModel()`:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context
): ViewModel() {

}
```

> Here I note when using Hilt to inject Application Context into the ViewModel. You will see a warning about memory leak when injecting the Application Context into the ViewModel. This is a warning in the recent Hilt version, but I have tested Profiler and there is no leak.

And you can get resource as string resource in ViewModel by calling:

```
val myText = context.getString(R.string.your_string_id)
```

Comment: in this case, when i use `...+ application.getString(R.string.pi_percent)` i get `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources() on a null object reference`. This resource exists, but i try it with others resources and get the same

Comment: A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context. Pass the context as parameter to the method instead

Comment: @Eduardo Sorry but I using `ApplicationContext`, not `ActivityContext`.

Comment: @Eduardo For more information why we can use the `ApplicationContext`, you can read in this link: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?authuser=2#implement. Thanks, bro!